# Is html_safe necessary when creating custom form helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a couple custom form helpers that I've built. I'm mostly happy with them although it seems that I have to put an `.html_safe` each time I call a method of the form builder class. Here are a couple examples.

Example 1:

```
  def mh_input(method, options = {})
    @template.content_tag(:div, class: 'form-group') do
      label(method, class: 'control-label').html_safe +
      @template.content_tag(:div, class: 'input-container') do
        input method, options.merge(class: 'form-control', label: false)
      end
    end
  end
```

Example 2:

```
  def form_buttons
    @template.content_tag(:div, class: 'form-group') do
      @template.content_tag(:div, class: 'col-lg-offset-2 input-container') do
        "#{crud_submit_button} #{cancel_button}".html_safe
      end
    end
  end
```

I understand why `.html_safe` is necessary. Is there a more elegant way to go about this, though, that somehow doesn't require the use of `.html_safe`?

Comment: Try using `concat` method instead of `+` to concat the elements https://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/